# read time from text file in java

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying to write some codes in java to read a text file, but when it read a time in (hh:mm) formate as example below:

```
6:30 14:30
```

and there is my java code to convert the string to Data formate

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
strLine = br.readLine();
strLine = strLine.trim();
tokens2 = strLine.split(" ");
System.out.println((Date)formatter.parse(tokens2[0]));
```

the output will be:

```
Thu Jan 01 06:30:00 AST 1970
```

it will give in long formate Date , While I want just take timezone(06:30).
what should I do ?
Any advice.

edit: the problem solved by Joda time by this code:

```
LocalTime.parse(tokens2[0]);
```

it is just take time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, your time pattern is wrong - you should be using `HH:mm` as you're using a 24-hour clock in your examples.

Secondly, you're parsing a `Date`. A `Date` is just an instant in time: it doesn't know about the time zone, calendar, whether you're interested in just the time, just the date etc.

Thirdly, you're seeing that output because you're basically just calling `Date.toString()`.

There's no type in Java to represent just "a time of day" (which isn't at all the same as a time zone, by the way). You could *format* a `Date` to just include the time part, but *if* you want to do that, I'd strongly recommend using a time zone of UTC to avoid any possible DST problems.

A better solution would be to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.googlecode.com) which has a [`LocalTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) type - ideal for your situation. You can parse that ([`DateTimeFormatter.parseLocalTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseLocalTime%28java.lang.String%29)) and then work with it appropriately, formatting it (again to just a time) whenever you want.

Comment: thanks for answer, I didn't used Joda Time before , but I was downloaded Joda Time , and I should add jar files to netbeans?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to read and parse `6:30` and output it as `06:30`, right?

Well, a first step would be to use the formatter, to output the date again:

```
System.out.println(formatter.format((Date)formatter.parse(tokens2[0])));
```

Btw, your format would not be able to correctly format `14:30` since `h` means the hour in am/pm, e.g. 1-12. Your format should be `HH:mm` instead, otherwise you'd get the output `02:30` instead of `14:30`.

Comment: In my experience, `kk` (01-24) is much rarer than `HH` (00-23).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `SimpledateFormatter` in two ways.

1. to parse a String and create a Date
2. to create a String aout of a Date

You want both in your example. 
First you want to parse a String and create a Date (even if you are only interestet in the time part). In the second step you want to create a String out of this Date and print it to System.out.

```
Date date=formatter.parse(tokens2[0]);     //use the 'formatter' to parse the String
Sytem.out.println(formatter.format(date)); //use the 'formatter' to define the format of the output.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using java.time

The other answers are correct but now outdated.

The [`java.time.LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class represents a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone. The class can directly parse a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format using 24-hour clock: HH:MM or HH:MM:SS

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "14:30" );
String output = lt.toString();  // 14:30
```

### Formatting

Use a `DateTimeFormatter` if you want other formats. Even localize automatically.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL );
f = f.withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ); // Cultural norms & human language
String output = lt.format( f );
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.